# rewrite rule, no clue

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to redirect

`pins?board=10000011`

to

`view_photos.php?album=10000011`

`10000011` being an id that is dynamic, therefore the no clue in the title of this question, do not know how to grab that and use inside a rewrite rule.

have tried with:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-0-9-_.]+)/pins?board= $1/view_photos.php?album=$2
```

it seems I obviously don't know exactly what I'm doing so I'm asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't match against the query string in a rewrite rule. You need to use the `%{QUERY_STRING}` var in a rewrite condition:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^board=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/?([A-Za-z-0-9-_.]+)/pins$ /$1/view_photos.php?album=%1 [L,R=301]
```